# How to generate model classes from existing sql server DB

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ado.net

I have a website running using ASP & Entity Framework. Now i think to build a Xamarin Application for IOS & Android.

I generate the model classes from Db (used Code first from db ADO).

**Now I'm wondering if i can generate the classes in Xamarin app as i did in my ASP App? Or i should do other methods to generate / write the classes ?**

And one more **question**: Does the connection string in Xamarin same as ASP?

I did a little search about this, but i did not get a clear answer to make me think how i should start!

Comment: Because of the security (and various other reasons) connecting to a remote database from mobile clients is not a good practice. You need to develop an Api and expose endpoints for mobile clients to consume.

Comment: So i Should Write my DB Classes and Define The relation manually ? and when i want to call the DB I should use API Layer Btw App & DB ?

Comment: If your app is purely online (no SQLite) you'll have classes (models or entities) that are mapped to Api inputs. No need to maintain the relations on client side. On the server side, convert the entities to DBClasses and do the operations. I'd suggest you go through [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers), just ignore the microservices part if you don't need it.